# PHP форма отправляет на емейл пустые строки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть PHP форма, работает хорошо, но присылает мне пустые строки,а выглядят они так:
Имя:
Отчество:
Email:
Сообщение:

Только что выявил, что значения в переменные вообще не записываются, в чем может быть проблема?

```js
 <?php
 
 if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["second"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["message"])) {
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $second = $_POST["second"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $message = $_POST["message"];
 }

 $to = "ololololololo@gmail.com";
 $subject = "A new message from website!";
 $body = "Имя:" . $name ."\n" . "Отчество:" . $second ."\n" . "Имейл: " .$email ."\n" . "Сообщение:" . $message;
 $header = "From :" .$email;

 if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {
  echo "Success";
 }
 else {
  echo "Fail";
 }
 ?>
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="form" action='main.php' name="form">
      <div class="input-1">
        <label for="">Имя:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Иван" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" name="name" id="name">
      </div>
      <div class="input-1">
        <label for="">Отчество:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Иванович" required="required" name="second" id="second">
      </div>
      <div class="email">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
      </div>
      <input type="email" placeholder="example@mail.ru" required="required" name="email" id="email">
      <div class="message">
        <label for="area">Сообщение:</label>
      </div>
      <textarea cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Введите сообщение..." required="required" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
      <div class="sbm">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить">
      </div>
    </form>
```

Товарищи, прошу помощи!

Answer (score 1):

Всё, решил проблему сам, просто записал значения в переменные дополнительно дубляжом, только без isset.

Answer (score 0):

**UPD:** как я и предполагал, проблема в вашем сервере, так как у меня с exim4 всё работает. Если вы размещаетесь на хостинге - пишите в техподдержку. Если у вас свой VDS/VPS, то установите почтовый сервер.

Как минимум сделайте так:

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["second"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["message"])) {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $second = $_POST["second"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $to = "ololololololo@gmail.com";
    $subject = "A new message from website!";
    $body = "Имя:" . $name ."\n" . "Отчество:" . $second ."\n" . "Имейл: " .$email ."\n" . "Сообщение:" . $message;
    $header = "From :" .$email;

    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {
        echo "Success";
    }
    else {
        echo "Fail";
    }
  } else {
    echo 'Поля пусты.';
  }
?>
```

Может, вы почему-то не отправляете данные? Но чую я, что у вас что-то не так с mail().

Comment: На хостинге функция работает отлично. Только что выявил, что оказывается значения вообще не записываются в переменную. В чем может быть проблема?